# EmailServiceImpl - Authentication failed - no password specified? (anonymous access)

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have setup a local SMTP server on my server machine's IIS 6.0. 
I have set its Access Control to Anonymous so that no user name or password is required. The SMTP Windows service is running and I am trying the following in my server.xml to send an email:

```
<Resource auth="Container" mail.smtp.host="192.168.27.158"  mail.smtp.auth="true" mail.smtp.port="25"  name="sas/mail/Session" type="javax.mail.Session"/>
```

The host IP above is what I get when I run my `ipconfig` and look for the value `IPv4` under my domain's Ethernet.

The message I get in the log is the following:

> com.sas.mobiledesigner.api.services.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl -
>   Authentication failed; nested exception is
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no
>   password specified?

Why is the it asking for password when I have set my access control to anonymous?

**Update:**

After setting the value of `mail.smtp.auth` to `false` I get the following error message:

> ERROR [tomcat-http--10] 2016-05-24 16:22:56,416 
>   com.sas.mobiledesigner.api.services.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl - Mail
>   server connection failed; nested exception is
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   192.168.27.158, port: 25, response: -1. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   192.168.27.158, port: 25, response: -1

Comment: The client settings don't match what the server is configured for.  See the [connection debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  You ran ipconfig on the Windows machine, not on your Tomcat machine, right?

Comment: @BillShannon they are both on the same machine. (Windows and Tomcat)

Comment: Did you try connecting with telnet?  If you have firewall or anti-virus software running on the Windows machine, try disabling it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think auth property should be false.

```
mail.smtp.auth="false"
```

Comment: oh thanks. let me go try once more and come back to you.

Comment: I did what you said. I have updated the question with the new error message. Please check.